# Jar file copy with eclipse plugin issue

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I've been writing an eclipse plugin for those familiar with Google's App Inventor, and looking to take the next step into programming with eclipse and the android SDK. The plugin is essentially the same as the ADT plugin's new Android Project wizard, only it copies over some different files.

All of the files are text based except for a library file (which gets put into the lib directory, and added to the build path).

This all works fine if I hit F11 (to test the plugin in a seperate eclipse instance). However, when I create a feature, and then an update site, something goes wrong. I can install the plugin fine, but when using the new wizard, it doesn't copy the jar file (although the lib still gets added to the build path).

I'm at my wits end trying to figure out why the file copies in one situation, and not in the other (I checked the plugin jar file, and the lib is in there).

Comment: Got it. Had to convert the inputstream to a byte array, then create a new inputstream from the byte array.